# Where is the MAF Sensor on a Peugeot 207?

Tags: peugeot, maf

I'm getting loss of power when idling and spluttering and the OBD is telling me the engine is running rich. I want to try cleaning or replacing the MAF sensor, but... I'm no mechanic and I'm just not able to find the thing in my Peugeot 207. It's a 2008 model, 1.6 petrol engine.

I've [Googled it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=where%20is%20the%20maf%20sensor%20on%20a%20peugeot%20207%202008&es_sm=122&biw=1920&bih=955&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=kdF5VJyTM8utafXkgpgL&ved=0CCsQ7Ak#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=Y7OIWzxgJXvz8M%253A%3BSBzgOrg2EpQDhM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.ytimg.com%252Fvi%252FAScWSqBPnbI%252Fhqdefault.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DAScWSqBPnbI%3B480%3B360) and watched various [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AScWSqBPnbI) and have [an image](http://www.bavariandominator.co.uk/pages/peugeot_maf_sensors_123427.cfm) of what the part looks like, but still can't seem to locate it when looking into the engine bay from above. Can anyone help?

Comment: If what I'm reading is correct, only the 207 with the diesel engine uses a MAF.

Comment: If it does have a MAF, it would be located between the air box and the throttle body. The image you posted above (last link) is one for an HDi engine, which I'm assuming is the Peugeot diesel.

Answer (score 1):

The Peugeot 207 petrols have a little bit of a reputation for clogging up on the throttle body. Using a tin of throttle body cleaner and a common bath room tooth brush, remove the hose to the throttle body. Spray in and around the throttle and clean off any 'dirt' with the tooth brush. Hold the throttle blade open and clean as much as possible in and around it. Give it all a good spray. Re-assemble the hose to the throttle body and start the engine. You may have to spin the engine a little to clear the throttle body cleaner fluid from the system. You should now notice a real differance.

Answer (score 0):

The part has to be between the air cleaner and the throttle body, find a part that is connected with rubber hoses and has a wire connected to it. You might need to remove the air filter box to see the MAF.